# Accessing element property from inside function on event call - this

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, this

So I wonder if anyone knows why this is the case. I declare a function and then give it a property value as below. I bind the function to a click event on an element. The click event works - it calls the function.

```
$settings.xClick = function(event){
    console.log($(this)); 
}
$settings.xClick.x = "test";

$("#xyz").bind("click", {}, $settings.xClick);
```

The problem that x does not seem to be in the function scope.

Suggestions on the correct way to access x when inside the function?

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning `x` as a property of `$settings.xClick`. A function, just like any other object, can have properties.

It's important though to differentiate between the local scope of that function (upon each call, stuff declared like `var foo = ...` within the function) and the properties of the function. To access `x` within the function `xClick` you'll have to access it like so:

```
$settings.xClick = function(event){
    console.log( $settings.xClick.x ); 
};
$settings.xClick.x = "test";
// ...
```

Comment: Is that really the only way to get the context? $settings.xClick.x? I am trying to give this function some easily accessible data & functions to be accessed by the end user. They provide the event, and the plugin sets some default settings and methods for them to access.